# $\mathrm{col}(AB) = \mathrm{col}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a real invertible $n\times n$ matrix, and $B$ a real $n\times m$ matrix. $\mathrm{col}(.)$ denotes the column space of a matrix.

What are the conditions for $\mathrm{col}(AB) = \mathrm{col}(B)$ in terms of the eigenvectors of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $B$ has rank $m$. Then $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=m$ and $\mathrm{col}(AB)=\mathrm{col}(B)$ is equivalent to the existence of an $m\times m$ nonsingular matrix $M$ such that $AB=BM$. If $M$ is diagonalisable ($M=XDX^{-1}$ for some diagonal $D$ and nonsingular $X$), then $AB=BXDX^{-1}$ gives $A(BX)=(BX)D$ and hence the columns of $B$ are a basis of some invariant subspace of $A$ (formed from eigenvectors corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues of $A$).

Comment: Thanks, I have a question about your answer. What does the assumption that $M$ is diagonalisable imply in terms of $A$ and $B$? What if  $M$ is not diagonalisable?

Comment: @mark If $M$ is not diagonalisable, then $A$ as well. Then $\mathrm{col}(B)$ is not spanned only by eigenvectors but also by generalised eigenvectors. In any case, $\mathrm{col}(B)$ is certain invariant subspace of $A$ (corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues of $A$).

Comment: How do you show that if $A$ is diagonalisable then $M$ is? Apologies if this is trivial. Also, you showed that, if $A$ is diagonalizable and $B$ has rank $m$, $\mathbb{col}(B)$ is spanned by $m$ eigenvectors of $A$. Given that $A$ and $B$ are real, do I need to give special consideration to the case when $A$ has nonreal complex eigenvalues? Many thanks.